# Error Java Rest API

Tags: java

estoy teniendo un problema en la cual me sale este error, no se porque motivo cuando trato de abrir el url de una api rest que cree en Java.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es un error. Hay navegadores que descargan los contenidos con el content-type `application/json`. Lo mas probable es que haya que configurar el netbeans para que lo muestre en vez de descargarlo.

Comment: Como lo puedo configurar en Eclipse

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas un navegador normal o Postman?

Comment: Uso el Postman tambie, Muy aparte de eso desde que me sale esa advertencia me sale un error Que no me puedo conectar a la base de datos

Comment: Es raro ya que el proyecto Java lo pruebo en otra maquina y me sale todo normal, y lo traslado en otra maquina y me sale esto

Comment: Una API Rest NO forzosamente debe verse en el navegador, al final sólo se requiere un EndPoint a donde hacerle la petición web, pero no por eso debes ver algo.

Comment: Por favor editá la pregunta, aclará cuales son los errores, fijate si hay excepciones en la consola de java, y agrega lo que sea relevante del stack strace. Y agregá el código que lleva a esos errores.